# MvvmCross - Experiencing ViewModel registration issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm having an error which I quite don't know why I'm getting.

**ShellPage.cs:**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        fragmentManager = FragmentManager;

        RegisterFragments(bundle);

        .
        .
        .

        ViewModel.ShowMenu();
        ViewModel.ShowFirstContent();
    }

    private void RegisterFragments(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RegisterFragment<MenuContent, MenuContentViewModel>(typeof(MenuContent).Name);
        RegisterFragment<AddChildContent, AddChildContentViewModel>(typeof(AddChildContent).Name);
    }

    public bool Show(MvxViewModelRequest request, Bundle bundle)
    {
        .
        .
        .

        if (request.ViewModelType == typeof(MenuContentViewModel))
        {
            ShowFragment(typeof(MenuContent).Name, Resource.Id.left_drawer, bundle);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowFragment(request.ViewModelType.Name, Resource.Id.content_frame, bundle);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**ShellPageViewModel.cs**

```
    public class ShellPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public void ShowMenu()
        {
            ShowViewModel<MenuContentViewModel>();
        }

        public void ShowFirstContent()
        {
            ShowViewModel<SelectChildContentViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Basically, when **ShowFirstContent**() is called, I get the folowing error:

```
    Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not find tag: SelectChildContentViewModel in cache, you need to register it first.
```

When **RegisterFragment**() is called from the **OnCreate**(), it raises no errors, so I assume that it registers the fragment and viewmodel correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

The code I used is all based on James Montemango's code:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.NavDrawer/tree/master/Material%20(Lollipop%20Style)/MvvmCross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in there has some critical bugs. I would recommend looking into: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

The code used there is:

```
    private void RegisterForDetailsRequests(Bundle bundle)
    {
        RegisterFragment<MenuFragment, MenuViewModel>(typeof(MenuViewModel).Name, bundle);
        RegisterFragment<ExamplesFragment, ExamplesViewModel>(typeof(ExamplesViewModel).Name, bundle);
        RegisterFragment<SettingsFragment, SettingsViewModel>(typeof(SettingsViewModel).Name, bundle);
    }

    public void RegisterFragment<TFragment, TViewModel>(string tag, Bundle args)
        where TFragment : IMvxFragmentView
        where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
    {
        var customPresenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFragmentsPresenter>();
        customPresenter.RegisterViewModelAtHost<TViewModel>(this);
        RegisterFragment<TFragment, TViewModel>(tag);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Works like a charm!  I revisited all the code and following the example you provided in the link, the app runs and loads with the drawer exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much!!   :)

Comment: Martijn, I have a question. Is there a sample for MvvmCross that demonstrates navigation in a Windows app for a single page (I'm using a SplitView in Windows 10 on one page and need all the navigation to occur in the SplitView and not between multiple pages)?

Comment: I don't know of such example, but you should look into custom presenters for MvvmCross. They should be able to handle that case. Other then that you can make an issue in the mvvmcross samples repo to request a sample of this.

Comment: One final question, sorry to keep bothering you. Is there an example of any Presenter done in a .net project (phone, or RT, or shared project), even if it doesn't match what I need?  Thanks for your time. This will at least give me an idea about how to start implementing one for UWP.

Comment: There is no example of this currently, but it should be quite standard to extend the UWP presenter and add your own implementation.